# positioning first letter as list-style outside

Tags: html, css

I have a template on which there is not defined list by `<ul><li></li></ul>` but as following

html

```
<div>• some text here long text here</div>
<div>• some text here long text here</div>
<div>• some text here long text here</div>
```

css

```
div{width: 100px;}
```

Which produce like this

> • some text here
>
> long text here

I can't change this because of larger contents i.e. I have to change more than one thousands articles. So I wish to change this with css so that it will become like this

> • some text here
>
> ```
> long text here
> ```

That is indenting first letter as `list-style-position: outside; we do in <ul>`

Is there any technique to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M6jak/)

You can do this by setting hanging indent:

```
padding-left: 15px; text-indent: -10px;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275081/positioning-first-letter-as-list-style-outside/17275206#17275206

Comment: Yeah! At the same time. But padding-left is more precious than margin-left suppose if you have applied a background in that div.

Comment: True, but the OP has not mentioned having background. He wanted the thing to be like list style type appearance, weather you give a margin or padding or dont just give anything, text-indent is what solves the purpose and margin or padding is just to give him a space to see that his thing is working with text-indent which is my exact point and that has already been answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275081/positioning-first-letter-as-list-style-outside/17275206#17275206

Comment: Why are you reffering to your question always as both answers came to same time. This is not good.

Comment: Sorry to say, but it has not come at the same time, I was early and you can verify that, but I am not here to argue upon points or snatch any ones reputation from this argument. I share my knowledge and weather you have copied my answer or it is a co-incidence is not relevant to me anymore. The OP got the solution and that serves it all.

Comment: just 1 minute before how could I copy your code and change the things? I was having a problem in my browser otherwise, I would have answered 10 mins before you. Got it?

Comment: You are the best judge of yourself so no point in discussing it again and again.

Comment: um! why are you saying like that? Just be SO friend n nothing else.

Comment: Sure. If you have any programming queries, you are most welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done.

Here is the [WORKING SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/W6EbE/)

**Your HTML:**

```
<div>• some text here long text here</div>
<div>• some text here long text here</div>
<div>• some text here long text here</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
div {
    margin-left: 19px;
    text-indent: -12px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
div {
    margin-left: 19px;
    text-indent: -12px;
    width: 100px;
}
</style>
<body>

        <div>• some text here long text here</div>
<div>• some text here long text here</div>
<div>• some text here long text here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275081/positioning-first-letter-as-list-style-outside/17275206#17275206 Already Answered. And your values are also identically same as the answer.